# How to set up .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint in Identity Server

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

I'm new to OpenID Connect and Identity Server, I'm trying to set up a test server instance using the sample code from the [IdentityServer3.Samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples) MVC Authentication project.  The problem is that I don't see where a .well-known config endpoint is set up there and I'm not sure how to go about setting that up.  I've done a lot of searching for how to do this but have come up empty.  I also followed [this article](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/2016/11/identityserver-openid-connect-and.html) from Dylan Beattie (minus ngrok) but it seems to ignore the fact that there is no .well-known endpoint in the sample project.  How do I set up the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovery endpoint is implemented in IdentityServer3 itself:

[`WebApiConfig.cs`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/Configuration/Hosting/WebApiConfig.cs)

```cs
if (options.Endpoints.EnableDiscoveryEndpoint)
            {
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    Constants.RouteNames.Oidc.DiscoveryConfiguration,
                    Constants.RoutePaths.Oidc.DiscoveryConfiguration,
new { controller = "DiscoveryEndpoint", action = "GetConfiguration" });
```

Here is the DiscoveryEndpoint controller [`DiscoveryEndpointController.cs`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/Endpoints/Connect/DiscoveryEndpointController.cs)

```cs
/// <summary>
/// GET
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Discovery document</returns>
     [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetConfiguration()
     {
         Logger.Info("Start discovery request");

         var baseUrl = Request.GetIdentityServerBaseUrl();
         var allScopes = await _scopes.GetScopesAsync(publicOnly: true);
         var showScopes = new List<Scope>();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I downloaded the source and see that controller and config.  However, I'm struggling to see how I can incorporate that into the MVC Authentication sample.  I'm not new to Web API and MVC, but this OpenId stuff is new.  I'm guessing I'll have to take the discovery controller and config along with all dependencies and put them in the MVC Authentication project if I want that functionality?

Comment: @AK3800 You don't need to build anything, it's part of the library (which I assume you install through nuget). The middleware should take care of the routing.

Comment: Ok, I see that now, you are correct.  The MVC Authentication sample project references the IdentityServer3 dll.  When I run the project locally I am able to get to the identity/.well-known/openid-configuration.  Once I deploy it to a development environment I'm getting a 404 trying to get at it there.  I had to replace the localhost references within the code with the site name of the development site, that may be the problem I'm running into.  Thank you for explaining the config endpoint and where it was coming from, this definitely helps me understand what I was missing!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than amend the above answer, those looking for the .well-known/openid-configuration which use IdentityServer will need to look in the mapped folder you define in the Startup class.

for example:

app.Map("/core", coreApp =>

which would change the root path you publish for others as [website]/core/.well-known/openid-configuration

This was not initially obvious to me since I wrongly assumed the root path would be assumed for consistency of services I have consumed.